# update on duplicate key, command not properly ended

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, insert-update

I serached alot and found some similar cases but non of them helped me to make it work, they are all somehow different,So I have this query:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO dev_corpus"  
  +"(corpusid,corpus_name,corpusdesc,corpusimageids,rocf1,rocf2,rocf3,rocc1,rocc2,rocc3,corpusactive,corpusrunfrequency,corpuslastrun,corpuslastsync,rocsettingid,corpusaffinity,corpusterms,corpusdomain) VALUES"  
  +"(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"  
  +"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "  
  +"corpusid = VALUE(?)"; // I have also tried VALUES
```

and it throws me this error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended  
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)  
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
```

and here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "SBOOKS"."DEV_CORPUS"   
   (    "CORPUSID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,   
    "CORPUS_NAME" VARCHAR2(768 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,   
    "CORPUSDESC" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),   
    "CORPUSIMAGEIDS" VARCHAR2(768 BYTE),   
    "ROCF1" FLOAT(63),   
    "ROCF2" FLOAT(63),   
    "ROCF3" FLOAT(63),   
    "ROCC1" FLOAT(63),   
    "ROCC2" FLOAT(63),   
    "ROCC3" FLOAT(63),   
    "CORPUSACTIVE" NUMBER(3,0),   
    "CORPUSRUNFREQUENCY" NUMBER(3,0),   
    "CORPUSLASTRUN" DATE,   
    "CORPUSLASTSYNC" DATE,   
    "ROCSETTINGID" NUMBER(3,0),   
    "CORPUSAFFINITY" NUMBER(3,0),   
    "CORPUSTERMS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),   
    "CORPUSDOMAIN" NUMBER(3,0),   
     PRIMARY KEY ("CORPUSID")  
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS   
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645  
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)  
  TABLESPACE "DDATA"  ENABLE  
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING  
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645  
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)  
  TABLESPACE "DDATA" ;
```

can you tell me what is wrong I try to run it in MYSQL gives me the same error. do you know what part of my query is wrong? how can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: possibly space missing after the value list ?? `+"(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
+" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "`

Comment: This table def is for Oracle, isn't it? If so, note that the equivalent Oracle operation is [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).

Comment: @EdGibbs good one. No one else expected the wrong type of DB :)

Comment: thanks I have added the spaces!:) but still doesnt work!

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: wow! thank youuu! that should be it! let me try with MERGE and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space after your VALUES list, before the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO dev_corpus"
 +"(corpusid,corpus_name,corpusdesc,corpusimageids,rocf1,rocf2,rocf3,rocc1,rocc2,rocc3,corpusactive,corpusrunfrequency,corpuslastrun,corpuslastsync,rocsettingid,corpusaffinity,corpusterms,corpusdomain) VALUES"
 +"(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
 +"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
 +"corpusid = VALUE(?)"; // I have also tried VALUES
```

The first line below see I put a space between the ) and "...

```
 +"(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) "
 +"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
```